# click function to add element and update html

Tags: jquery

if I have an array of table list items:

```
<div id="target">
    <ul>
        <li>list item 1</li>
        <li>list item 2</li>
        <li>list item 3</li>
        <li>list item 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and I want to construct a click function that adds an 'li' and increments the inner html of each item, I can write:

```
var listItems = $('#target ul li');
var newItem = document.createElement('li');
newItem.innerHTML = "list item " + (parseInt(listItems.size()) + 1);

$("#target").click(function() {
    var list = $('#target ul');
    list.append(newItem);
});
```

which works, but only once. why won't it add a list item every time I click it?

Comment: You have to create new item with each click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fix... you should create your element inside the event listener:

```
var list = $('#target ul');

$("#target").click(function() {
    var newItem = document.createElement('li');
    newItem.innerHTML = "list item " + (list.find("li").length + 1);
    list.append(newItem);
});
```

**Note:** I've replaced the `.size()` with `.length`. [It's faster and does the exact same thing](http://api.jquery.com/size/) :)

Comment: This will not work.  `listItems.length` will always be the same value you either have to create `listItems` with each click.  Even `.size()` has the same result (I thought it would be different).

Comment: I used .size() and it worked as long as I placed it within the event listener like you guys suggested. I too thought .length would be more efficient but I didn't test it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create newItem with each click:

```
var $list = $('#target ul');
$('#target ul').click(function() {
    var newItem = document.createElement('li');
    newItem.innerHTML = "list item " + ($list.children().length + 1);
    $list.append(newItem);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2EZd/)

You can also create an item as a template and reuse it, which is maybe what you're going for?

```
var $cloneItem = $('<li />');
var $list = $('#target ul');
$("#target").click(function () {
    $list.append($cloneItem.clone().html('list item ' + ($list.children().length + 1)));
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2EZd/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Your just re-appending (removing and then appending again) the same LI object. You have to create a new LI inside of your click function.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
$("#target").click(function() {
    $(this).find('ul')
        .append($('<li/>')
        .text('list item '+$(this).find('ul li').length+1));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**The real question here is, why create a new one on each click ?**

If you log `newItem` before `list.append` you will see that it exists.
[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Ct22/)

Why don't simple change it's text and then append, like the following code ?

```
var $list = $('#target ul'),
    $listItems = $list.find('li'),
    newItem = document.createElement('li');

$("#target").click(function() {
    newItem.innerHTML = "list item " + (parseInt($listItems.size()) + 1);
    $list.append(newItem);
});
```

The code above will not work, the problem is that `newItem.innerHTML` will reference always the same element that was appended for first. You can see this behavior [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/2Ct22/1/).

That's why you have to create a new element on each click.